# Is there an R function to prevent some lines of the code to be executed

Tags: r, function, optimization, comments

I would like to know if there is an R function that allows to prevent some lines of the code to be executed.

For instance, if this function exist and is called prevent, I could put on my code at line number 10 :

prevent(line12, line17)

and those line wouldn't be executed.

The application for me would pe to prevent some line which are in a loop to be executed, if a condition that I would test **before** going in the loop is not satisfyed.

It's a matter of optimization : I could test the condition inside the loop but I would rather test it before, since I already know wheter the condition is true or not.

Here is an example :

```
         Condition=T

         if (Condition){
           Dont execute line 17
         }

         for (i in 1:n){
line 17    Print("I'm happy")
         }
```

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. Imagine your loop gets bigger. Now you have some lines that invisibly won't be run because of code written much earlier in the file. A recipe for confusion. If you really want to play this way, you can investigate `body()<-` for messing with the body of a function.

Comment: I understant it's a bad idea, but I'm still surprised, I thought it was a common issue. Thanks for the answer anyway, I'll look at the body function.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use an `if` statement:

```
condition <- T

for (i in 1:3) {
  if (condition) {
    cat("Execute this \n")
  }
}
```

Comment: The thing is I want to test the condition before the loop

Comment: Condition evaluation is done before the loop. I took a simple example `Condition <- T` but you could evaluate whatever you need., like `Condition <- A == B`

Comment: Yes but you do the test inside the for, I wish the test of condition was before the for

Comment: I won't be able to help further without a code example of what you're looking for.

Comment: I'have add an example to the original message

Comment: For the example you provided, replacing `if(condition)` by `if(!condition) {...}` would work in my answer. As mentioned in comments, targeting a specific line number is bad practice because the number of lines might change and this would break the logic.

Comment: Ok, so I'll make the test in the loop, it doesnt cost much anyway ! thanks

Comment: yeah it's not an answer for what I asked, because I knew I could do that, I said it in my original message

Answer (score 1):

you could just add an "#" before the code line you don't want to execute

```
# 2+2
2+2
```

You can do it for multiple lines with cmd+shift+c in studio in mac, there should be an Linux or windows equivalent